# Not able to set IsSelected to true for specific combo box item

Tags: wpf, combobox

> Error:System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames'
> animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Background'
> because it is of incompatible type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush.

XML Error Code:

```
<ComboBox    Canvas.Left="-13" Canvas.Top="11" Height="29"  Name="cbDeviceTypeSelection"   Width="147" Text="18" SelectionChanged="cbMeterTypeSelection_SelectionChanged_1" >
                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True"  Content="Energy Meter"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Flow Meter"/>
            </ComboBox>
```

Complete XML Code for reference:

```
<Window x:Class="GES_ServiceManager.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:gridColumn="clr-namespace:GES_ServiceManager.GridView_Controls" 
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GES_ServiceManager"
     xmlns:control="clr-namespace:GES_ServiceManager.LoadingControl"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    
    
   Title="GES-Service Manager" Height="610" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Width="790" Style="{DynamicResource MetroWindowStyle}"  MinHeight="534" MaxWidth="790" MaxHeight="734" MinWidth="790" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="/GES-ServiceManager;component/Resources/Greenovative_icon.ico"  WindowStyle="None" StateChanged="Window_StateChanged" Closed="Window_Closed" Closing="Window_Closing" >
<Window.Resources>
    
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="MetroWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="MainBorder"   BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Background="#333" >
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                                <Border x:Name="PART_TITLEBAR" 
                                        Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="40" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  
                                        Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="PART_TITLEBAR_MouseLeftButtonDown" >
                                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                                            <Image Margin="7,1,1,1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="Resources\logo-2.png" Height="50" Width="150" Stretch="None" />
                                            <TextBlock  Visibility="Hidden" Margin="4,0,0,4" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   Foreground="#FFAAAAAA" TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" FontSize="16" />
                                        <Button x:Name="PART_CLOSE" DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"
                                                Height="45" Width="45" 
                                                Style="{DynamicResource MetroWindowButtonStyle}"
                                                Click="PART_CLOSE_Click">
                                            <Path Data="F1M54.0573,47.8776L38.1771,31.9974 54.0547,16.1198C55.7604,14.4141 55.7604,11.6511 54.0573,9.94531 52.3516,8.23962 49.5859,8.23962 47.8802,9.94531L32.0026,25.8229 16.1224,9.94531C14.4167,8.23962 11.6511,8.23962 9.94794,9.94531 8.24219,11.6511 8.24219,14.4141 9.94794,16.1198L25.8255,32 9.94794,47.8776C8.24219,49.5834 8.24219,52.3477 9.94794,54.0534 11.6511,55.7572 14.4167,55.7585 16.1224,54.0534L32.0026,38.1745 47.8802,54.0534C49.5859,55.7585 52.3516,55.7572 54.0573,54.0534 55.7604,52.3477 55.763,49.5834 54.0573,47.8776z" 
                                            Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFF" Width="10" Margin="0,0,0,0" ></Path>
                                        </Button>
                                        <!--<Button  x:Name="PART_MAXIMIZE_RESTORE" 
                                                DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                Height="20" Width="20" Style="{DynamicResource MetroWindowButtonStyle}"
                                                Click="PART_MAXIMIZE_RESTORE_Click">
                                            <Path Data="M4.3685131,23.127279L4.3685131,47.283243 47.117023,47.283243 47.117023,23.127279z M0,10.684L53.755001,10.684 53.755001,51.668001 0,51.668001z M8.5679998,0L58.668022,0 64,0 64,5.6864691 64,45.317999 58.668022,45.317999 58.668022,5.6864691 8.5679998,5.6864691z"
                                                  Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFAAAAAA" Width="10" Margin="0,0,0,0" ></Path>
                                        </Button>-->
                                        <Button x:Name="PART_MINIMIZE" 
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"
                                                DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                                Height="40" Width="45" Style="{DynamicResource MetroWindowButtonStyle}"
                                                Click="PART_MINIMIZE_Click" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="1,8,1,1" >
                                            <Button.Content>
                                                <Path Data="M0,20L53.333,20 53.333,8.888 0,8.888z" 
                                                      Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFF" Width="10" Margin="5,0,0,5"></Path>
                                            </Button.Content>
                                        </Button>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </Border>

                                <AdornerDecorator DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"/>
                                </AdornerDecorator>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <AdornerDecorator>
                                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"/>
                                    </AdornerDecorator>
                                    <ResizeGrip x:Name="WindowResizeGrip" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsTabStop="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip"/>
                                        <Condition Property="WindowState" Value="Normal"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WindowResizeGrip" Value="Visible"/>
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
        
        <Style x:Key="MetroWindowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#333"/> 
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF707070"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#8C9196"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" TargetName="border" Value="Hand"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#8C9196"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF2C628B"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFADB2B5"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="#FF838383"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
   
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries\UserControlStyles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

   
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Width="787">
    <Grid Background="#f2f6f7"  x:Name="gridContainer" Margin="0,2,0,1">
    <Menu Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#2c689a" Name="menustrip" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="790">
            
            <MenuItem Header="Configuration" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  IsSubmenuOpen="False" Name="MenuConfiguration" Margin="9,0,0,0" Padding="-3,5,1,1"  FontFamily="Roboto" Foreground="#FFF" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" TabIndex="1" Click="MenuConfiguration_Click">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="Resources\Wrench.png" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="1,-2,3,1"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Autoreport" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsSubmenuOpen="False" Name="MenuAutoreport" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="9,0,0,0" Padding="-3,5,1,1"  FontFamily="Roboto" Foreground="#FFF" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" TabIndex="1" Click="MenuAutoreport_Click">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Resources\Log.png" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="1,-2,3,1"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
         </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Log" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsSubmenuOpen="False"  Margin="7,0,0,0" Padding="-3,5,1,1" Foreground="#FFF" FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold" TabIndex="2" Click="MenuLog_Click">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/GES-ServiceManager;component/Resources/Log.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Help"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,0,0,0" Padding="-3,5,10,1"  Foreground="#FFF" FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold" TabIndex="3" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                  <MenuItem.Icon >
                    <Image Source="Resources\Help.png" Height="18" Width="18" Margin="12,-1,4,1"/>
                  </MenuItem.Icon>
                <MenuItem Header="Help" IsSubmenuOpen="False" Foreground="#FFF" FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="15" FontWeight="DemiBold" />
                <MenuItem Header="About GreenErgy" IsSubmenuOpen="False" Foreground="#FFF" FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="15" FontWeight="DemiBold" Click="AboutGreenErgy_Click" />
            </MenuItem >
        </Menu>
    <StatusBar Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="lStatus" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="790" Background="White">
        <StatusBarItem>
            <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource StatusStyle}" Name="lblCurrentStatus" />
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
        <Popup Name="PopupRemark" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Left" StaysOpen="False"  Opened="PopupRemark_Opened" Visibility="Hidden" >
        <Grid x:Name="GrdPopup" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6" >
                <Border BorderBrush="#A9A9A9"  Background="#f2f6f7" CornerRadius="3" Padding="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="PopupBorder" >
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="18" Color="Black" Opacity="0.7"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="6">
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" FontSize="13" x:Name="PopupTitle"  FontWeight="Bold"  FontFamily="Roboto"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" />
                        <Separator></Separator>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PopupContent"  Foreground="#2c3e50" FontFamily="Roboto" FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <Polygon Points="19.1580170410534,9.57900852052672 4.78950426026336,17.8746732423704 4.78950426026335,1.28334379868299" Fill="#f2f6f7" Margin="-6.5,4,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Stroke="#f2f6f7" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
        
        <Canvas Height="448" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,43,0,0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="724">

            <ListView AlternationCount="2"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DeviceRowStyle}"  Canvas.Left="-14" Canvas.Top="10" Height="433"   Name="lstviewDevices" Padding="-1,0,-13,10" TabIndex="4" Width="150"  SelectionChanged="lstviewDevices_SelectionChanged" >
                
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                                    <Expander.Header>
                                                        <TextBlock FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    </Expander.Header>
                                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                                </Expander>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </ListView.GroupStyle>

                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Device" Width="145">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceName}" ToolTip="{Binding DeviceName}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Padding="2,4,3,2" Text="" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DeviceID}" gridColumn:GridViewColumnVisibilityManager.IsVisible="False" Header="DeviceID" Width="0" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            
            <ListView AlternationCount="2" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="10" Height="433" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MeterRowStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="lstviewMeters" Style="{StaticResource LstEMptyMessege}" TabIndex="5" Width="606" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Feeder" Width="195">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MeterName}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Padding="2,4,3,3" Text="Feeder" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="60">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MeterID}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Padding="2,4,3,3" Text="ID" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="80">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Padding="2,4,3,3" Text="Status" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="TimeStamp" Width="140">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeStamp}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Padding="2,4,3,3" Text="TimeStamp" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Remark" Width="128">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <ToggleButton Click="btnShowPopup_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="btnShowPopup" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}" Tag="{Binding Remark}">
                                            <Image Source="Resources\information.png" />
                                        </ToggleButton>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Padding="2,4,3,3" Text="Remark" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
            <ComboBox    Canvas.Left="-13" Canvas.Top="11" Height="29"  Name="cbDeviceTypeSelection"   Width="147" Text="18" SelectionChanged="cbMeterTypeSelection_SelectionChanged_1" >
                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True"  Content="Energy Meter"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Flow Meter"/>
            </ComboBox>
        </Canvas>
        <control:LoadingAnimation HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" x:Name="Loader"  Margin="380,160,298,205" Canvas.Left="-7" />
        <Canvas Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="450" Height="64" Name="canvas2" Width="476" Margin="159,486,131,47">
            <Button Canvas.Left="177" Canvas.Top="11" FontSize="16" Height="34" IsEnabled="True" Name="btnStartCommuncation" Style="{StaticResource btnCommunication}" TabIndex="6" Width="93" Click="btnStartCommuncation_Click">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="91">
                    <Image Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,0,-23,0" Source="Resources\Start_1.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                    <Label Content="START" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FFF" Margin="25,0,0,0" Padding="0,6,0,0" Width="52" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Canvas.Left="325" Canvas.Top="10" FontSize="14" Height="34" IsEnabled="True" Name="btnRestartCommunication" Style="{StaticResource btnCommunication}" TabIndex="6" Width="100" Click="btnRestartCommuncation_Click">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="91">
                    <Image Height="25" Margin="2,0,-23,0" Source="Resources\restart.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                    <Label Content="RESTART" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FFF" Margin="25,0,0,0" Padding="0,6,0,0" Width="93" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Canvas.Left="31" Canvas.Top="11" FontSize="16" Height="34" IsEnabled="True" Name="btnStopCommuncation" Style="{StaticResource btnCommunication}" TabIndex="7" Width="93" Click="btnStopCommuncation_Click">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,-23,0" Source="Resources\Stop_1.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                    <Label Content="STOP" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FFF" Margin="26,0,0,0" Padding="0,6,0,0" Width="52" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </Canvas>            
    </Grid>
    <ProgressBar Height="29"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="294,239,0,0" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253" IsIndeterminate="True" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" ClipToBounds="False"/>
    <Canvas Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="677,-7,0,0" Name="canvas3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114">
        <Button Canvas.Left="68" Canvas.Top="9" FontSize="16" IsEnabled="True" Name="btnLogout" Style="{StaticResource btnCommunication}" TabIndex="6" Width="33" Height="30" Click="btnLogout_Click">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="34" Height="32">
                <Image Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,-26,0" Source="Resources\logout.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Canvas>        
</Grid>
```

I have also tried to set SelectedIndex="0" but getting the same error.
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UJcp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used Styling to the window in Resources. So by default that applies to ComboBox you have used. See following code:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="MetroWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
```

The Background property System.Colors.WindowBrushKey does not allow to you to use IsSelected or SelectedIndex property. To fix this use seperate styling to your combobox items in Resources as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary>            
        <Style  TargetType="ComboBoxItem">                
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="MetroWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not shown us the animation that causes that error.

Somewhere.

You have a coloranimation.

As it's name suggests, this animates a color.

Yellow to red or whatever.

The error says this is incompatible with type brush.

Which it is.

Because a Brush is not a Color.

You have something like:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" x:Name="BrushBeingErroneouslyAnimated"/>
```

And some storyboard with a color animation whose targetname is your equivalent to "BrushBeingErroneouslyAnimated".
Or maybe you're just using the property path to the brush.

Instead, you should animate the colour a brush uses.

```
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation To="Red" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                Duration="0:0:2"/>
            </Storyboard>
```

Notice that this is pointing the animation to the Color property of the solidcolorbrush.